# How to Pass AWS credentials to docker compose network in Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-codebuild

I am running a docker compose network on AWS CodeBuild and I need to pass AWS credentials (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`) to the docker containers as they need to interact with AWS SSM. What is the best way to get these credentials from CodeBuild and pass them to the docker containers?

Initially, I thought of mounting the credentials directory from CodeBuild as a volume by adding this to each service in the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
volumes:
      - '${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials'
```

but that did not work as it seems the `${HOME}/.aws/` folder on the CodeBuild environment did not have any credentials in it

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker secret, you may create your secrets:

```
docker secret create credentials.cnf credentials.cnf
```

define your Keys in the credentials.cnf file, and include it in your compose file as below:

```
services:
   example:
       image:
       environment:
       secrets:
            - credentials.cnf


secrets:
  - AWS_KEY:
    file: credentials.cnf
  - AWS_SECRET:
    file: credentials.cnf
```

You can view your secrets with `docker secrets ls`

Answer (score 0):

In the environment section of the CodeBuild project you have an option to set the environment variable from the value stored in Parameter Store.